# Printing an array

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I have an array of 28 characters. I'm trying to use a for loop to print the string and its length so that the next line removes the last character from the previous line. For example:

```
7 Example
6 Exampl
5 Examp
4 Exam
3 Exa
2 Ex
1 E
```

I have this so far, but it's not printing. What am I doing wrong?

```
for(int index=28; index <= nameArray.length; index--)
            {
                System.out.print(nameArray[index]);
            }
```

Comment: Why does index start at 28? `index <= nameArray.length` will produce an error.  Why are you trying to print the array backwards?

Comment: Guys @ SO... It was the same question asked by this guy that was closed 2 days ago  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286524/using-an-if-statement-to-examine-an-array-in-java

Comment: It's not the same question. I have an assignment to do with multiple parts using the same array. I already figured that part out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is as simple as that ..

```
class A {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String array = "Example";

    for(int i=7;i>0;i--) {  
          System.out.print(i+" ");    
          System.out.println(array.substring(0, i)); 
        }
      } 
   }  

// Output :   
7 Example
6 Exampl
5 Examp
4 Exam
3 Exa
2 Ex
1 E
```

Answer (score 2):

If the length is 28 characters, you cannot start the index at 28.  Arrays in Java are zero-based, so that means that the index can range from 0 to 27 (length - 1).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you probably want your middle condition to be `index > 0`, not `index <= nameArray.length` (which should *always* be true, even as you enter the negative numbers).

Secondly, is it an array of *characters* you're accessing? If so, then as I'm sure you know, `nameArray[index]` refers to a *character*, not a string.

(Also, as [bobbymcr points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317341/printing-an-array/6317361#6317361), the top index in an array of 28 elements is 27, not 28.)

To print substrings, you should first initialize a `String` using your character array, *then* print increasingly smaller substrings using `substring`.

For example:

```
private static void printSubstrings(String input) {
    for (int length = input.length(); length > 0; length--) {
        System.out.printf("%d %s\n", length, input.substring(0, length));
    }
}
```

Then, if `nameArray` is a `char[]`, you could use the `String(char[])` constructor to pass to this method:

```
printSubstrings(new String(nameArray));
```

Example input:

```
char[] nameArray = new char[] { 'E', 'x', 'a', 'm', 'p', 'l', 'e' };
printSubstrings(new String(nameArray));
```

Output:

```
7 Example
6 Exampl
5 Examp
4 Exam
3 Exa
2 Ex
1 E
```

Answer (score 1):

Always remeber that the array indexes start from 0

```
[E][x][a][m][p][l][e] 
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6
```

I don't understand why you break your head with char arrays, when you have String.
Here i propose you a solution where:

1-transform the char[] to String

2-Iterate the String object and use the some methods from the String class to get the desired result:

```
public class Example
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       //Here an array with 28 characters
       char[] array = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p'
           ,'q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','!','@'};

      //For easier manipulation i will just transform that array to String
      //Why not, String was invented so we dont have to use char[].
      String arrayAsString = new String(array);

    //Use the methods that String class provides, to make the solution easier    
    for(int i=0;i < array.length;i++) {    
      System.out.println((i+1) + " " +  arrayAsString.substring(0,(arrayAsString.length()-i)));
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int index=28; index <= nameArray.length; index--)
```

First off, you're trying to start at index `28` - that doesn't exist. Arrays are `0` based which means they go from `0` to `length - 1`

Second, you're saying that the index has to be less than or equal to the length. Since you're going from the end to the start, that would always be true.

```
for (int index = nameArray.length - 1; index >= 0; index--)
```

That's what you're looking for.

Comment: In the last example, perhaps you mean `nameArray.length`